# figuring out where to put equalsIgnoreCase() to avoid case sensitivity

Tags: java, enums

I am using Spring 4 and making an API call using the following URL

I have a Java enum class which is defined as follows :

http://localhost.com:8080/int/fin/trs?bId=B-XYZ&sortBy=currentTs

And, I have the controller method where this call is receiving the parameters :

```
public ResponseEntity<SetRESTData<FinancialTransactionDTO>> getTFIUse(

    @RequestParam(value = "status", required = false) final String statusString,
    @RequestParam(value = "transactionMappableEnumthod", required = false) final String transactionMappableEnumthodString,
    @RequestParam(value = "sortBy", required = false) final String orderBy,
    @RequestParam(value = "sortDirection", required = false) final String sortDirectionString) {


    final FinancialTransactionPaginationData paginationData = StringUtils.isBlank(orderBy) ?
      null : new FinancialTransactionPaginationData(FinancialTransactionSortableField.fromCode(orderBy), null, null, sortDirectionString);


  }
```

The FinancialTransactionSortableField class is as follows :

```
public enum FinancialTransactionSortableField implements MappableEnum<FinancialTransactionSortableField>, SF {

  ID(DefaultSortableField.ID.getCode(), "T Id", DefaultSortableField.ID.getColumnNaMappableEnum()),
  CREATED_TS(DefaultSortableField.CREATED_TS.getCode(),
             DefaultSortableField.CREATED_TS.getDescription(),
             DefaultSortableField.CREATED_TS.getColumnNaMappableEnum()),;
```

The DefaultSortableField enum class is defined as follows :

```
public enum DefaultSortableField implements MappableEnum<DefaultSortableField>, SF {


  CREATED_TS("CreatedTs", "Created Timestamp", "CreatedTs"),;

  private final String code;
  private final String description;
  private final String columnName;

  private static final Map<String, DefaultSortableField> cmap =
    MappableEnum.buildCodeMap(DefaultSortableField.class);

  private DefaultSortableField(final String code, final String description, final String columnName) {
    this.code = code;
    this.description = description;
    this.columnName = columnName;
  }

  @JsonValue
  @Override
  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  @Override
  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  @Override
  public String getColumnName() {
    return columnName;
  }

  @Override
  public DefaultSortableField toEnum(final String code) {
    return fromCode(code);
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public static DefaultSortableField fromCode(final String code) {
    return cmap.get(code);
  }

  }
```

I am basically making an api call something like this http://localhost.com:8080/int/fin/trs?bId=B-XYZ&sortBy=CreatedTs 
  So when the code execution reaches the method DefaultSortableField.CREATED_TS.getCode() of FinancialTransactionSortableField class,The CreatedTs value(which is the first parameter of enum in DefaultSortableField CREATED_TS enum declaration gets returned. Everything is fine upto this point.However, when I pass sortBy=createdTs(notice the lowercase c ) in the above URL, it doesn't work. I am trying to figure out where to use equalsIgnoreCase() method , is it going to be somewhere in the FinancialTransactionSortableField class, somewhere on this line DefaultSortableField.CREATED_TS.getCode()

Comment: What is `ME` in `DefaultSortableField`?

Comment: @ skozlov Updated. It was typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@JsonCreator
public static DefaultSortableField fromCode(final String code) {
    for(String key : cmap.keySet()){
        if(code.equalsIgnoreCase(key)){
            return cmap.get(key);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```